# jenkins: Exception when publishing, exception message [Permission denied]

Tags: jenkins

when I bulid a project by using the plugin 'publish over ssh', jenkins shows me the error:

```
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [bc-ctq] in [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bc- 
ctq/target/bc-ctq]
[INFO] Processing war project    
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bc-        ctq/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [140 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bc-ctq/target/bc-ctq.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.018 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-26T19:38:10+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSH: Connecting from host [localhost.localdomain]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [love] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [love] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Permission denied]
Archiving artifacts
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

[Send files or execute commands over SSH after the build runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paKZX.png)

[the ssh server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtFMS.png)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar error and it turned out to be ownership issue. The owner of your project folder should be same as the one Jenkins uses to remote SSH into your instance.

Check ownership of your folder by running `ls -ltr` in your parent directory.

Change ownership using `sudo chown -R owner:group DirectoryName/`

Answer (score 0):

Check verbose output and start build, then you'll see where is the problem

[image: screenshot]